# How to save a return as string and use it in another method?

Tags: ruby, string, selenium, capybara

I'm new as Ruby programmer, and I'm developing an automation test using Ruby, Capybara etc. My System has a webtable, I need to get some cell value and send it in another method.

So I developed the follow code:

```
def capture_number()
            teste = @session.find("//*[@id=\"datagrid\"]/td[1]/div").text

            puts teste
end
```

Is it a string? And how can I send it in this field?

```
def fill_certification_no(field)
            @session.find(@path['fields']['field_name'].gsub("<field_id>", field)).set('')
end
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot use your data, but this simulates what you are looking for, if I understand the question. See inline comments:

```
@session = "abc def gjk"

def capture_number
  @session.split.last # something to look for
end

def fill_certification_no(field)
  @session << ' ' << field
end

capture_number #=> "gjk" # returns a String
fill_certification_no('xyz')
@session #=> "abc def gjk xyz"
```

So, call `capture_number` as argument:

```
fill_certification_no(capture_number)
@session #=> "abc def gjk xyz xyz"
```